# How do I count how many time an item exist in a column?

Tags: c#, mysql

[image]

I have a student table and a candidate table which a student can vote for a candidate, now my question is how can I show all candidates and their corresponding vote counts? I have used many-to-many relationship to keep track of which student voted for a specific candidate.

Comment: show us the sql statement you tried

Comment: In OOP "vote" does not belong to existence of student. You need another table containing votes. Student ID and Candidate ID (if an student can vote many candidates, Candidate ID should be the key, otherwise if student can vote once, Student ID should be the key). Using that table you can simply count items using SELECT COUNT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select c.candidateId, c.candidatename, 
       count(sc.candidate_tbl_candidateId) as vote_count
from candidate_tbl c
left join student_tbl_has_candidate_tbl sc on sc.candidate_tbl_candidateId = c.candidateId
group by c.candidateId, c.candidatename
```

Comment: Sir i meant show all the Fullname of all the Candidates, and how many times their CandidateId exist in the student_tbl_has_candidate_tbl. Sorry if i'm not being clear

Comment: And my query does exactly that. So what is the problem?

Comment: It show count = 1, even if the student_tbl_has_candidate_tbl is still empty

Comment: Perfect! Thank you sir.